# mariadb service is not starting after boot, CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot, systemd, services, mariadb

I defined the service for mariadb  on: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service

```
[Unit]
Description=start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target


[Service]
Type=simple
User=Umariadb
Group=Gmariadb
# Restart=always

# PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data 
# ExecStop=/usr/bin/vgaoff stop

TimeoutSec=300
PrivateTmp=true


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Later I activated it:

```
systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

Now, after reboot, the Service **is not starting**.

Then I need to disable the service again.

When trying to execute manually again it works perfectly...

```
sudo /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
```

**Is my script for service defined well?**

**I would like to know what is the problem is. How to solve it?**

EDIT:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
170308 19:54:07 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err'.
```

Inside the File

```
170308 19:54:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.20-MariaDB) starting as process 4411 ...
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1622938
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140587999135488 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-08 19:54:07 140588539000704 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-03-08 19:54:08 140588539000704 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.20-MariaDB'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

Testing Availability...

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 10.1.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Shutdown the Linux...

```
2017-03-08 19:59:29 140588538443520 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2017-03-08 19:59:29 140588538443520 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-03-08 19:59:29 140587982350080 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-03-08 19:59:29 140588538443520 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-03-08 19:59:31 140588538443520 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2017-03-08 19:59:32 140588538443520 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1622948
2017-03-08 19:59:32 140588538443520 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170308 19:59:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/Vxbox-Lnx.pid ended
```

**Now with service**...

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service to /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

**Checking**...

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ sudo service mariadb start
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mariadb.service
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

**STATUS**

```
$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
● mariadb.service - start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-08 20:09:47 COT; 5min ago
  Process: 4556 ExecStart=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 4556 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: Started start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server.
Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: Starting start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server...
Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx mysqld_safe[4556]: 170308 20:09:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err'.
Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Mar 08 20:09:47 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

**Another Check**

```
$ sudo systemctl --failed
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
  UNIT            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● kdump.service   loaded failed failed Crash recovery kernel arming
● mariadb.service loaded failed failed start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.                                                                                                        

2 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.                                                                                                         
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.                                                                                                                
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

Comment: When you try to start it by hand you do `sudo mysqld_safe ...`, so you are starting service as root user. In your service config file you have `User=Umariadb
Group=Gmariadb` and you end with `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
`.  Do you have some permission problems?

Comment: Yes, yesterday I was reviewing this. I will edit my question for more information.

Comment: Why are you writing your own MariaDB systemd file? Even if your OS didn't ship with one, surely there are ones available from other distributions that you could use as model.

Comment: @Kalavan this my ownership discovering... (antes de ayer, I don' know translate to english, yesterday of yesterday) of log file,  Now I checked if works...

Answer (score 2):

## Do not use `mysqld_safe`.

You have all sorts of problems, all down to building a contender for a place in the *systemd House of Horror* by running a Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor (written badly in shell script) underneath service management.  You could laboriously go through and tweak things so that they interoperate better, dealing with readiness protocol mismatches and with conflicts where you have ended up setting things two different ways in two different places, but that would really be pointless.  Instead, learn from the daemontools world, which has wanted `mysqld_safe` *gone* since the turn of the century.

All these years later, you can get rid of it in the systemd world, too.  The MariaDB world has the distinction, in stark contrast to Oracle and the MySQL world, of actually providing good doco on how to run MariaDB in the way that daemontools/runit/s6 users have wanted all of these years, without `mysqld_safe` and instead using the service management toolset for service management.

MariaDB *comes with* a `mariadb.service` service unit for systemd, and a `mariadb-service-convert` tool that migrates the settings from `my.cnf` into systemd service unit settings.  It even comes with a `mariadb@.service` service unit template, that allows one to run multiple servers as distinct services.  Use those.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[MariaDB and MySQL with nosh](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/mariadb-and-mysql.html)*.  Softwares.
- ["systemd"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/).  *Starting and Stopping MariaDB*.  KnowledgeBase.  MariaDB.  2016.
- ["Starting and Stopping MariaDB Automatically"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/starting-and-stopping-mariadb-automatically/).  *Starting and Stopping MariaDB*.  KnowledgeBase.  MariaDB.  2016.

Comment: Thank you... I was reading your article... have you a step by step?

Answer (score 0):

My Installation process was (before to ask)

```
sudo tar zxvf /media/sf_Users/josebernal/Downloads/Php\ Tomcat\ Httpd\ MySQL/mariadb-10.1.20-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mariadb-10.1.20-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb

sudo groupadd -r Gmariadb
sudo useradd -g Gmariadb -c "MariaDB User" -s /sbin/nologin -r Umariadb

sudo chown -R Umariadb:Gmariadb /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/
sudo cp /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/support-files/my-small.cnf /etc/my.cnf
... EDIT the config mariadb (mysql) file named my.cnf

sudo /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data --log-error=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err &
....
... The next steps..
```

Even before I reported (asked) the problem I checked Ownership ...

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ ls -al /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/
total 224
drwxrwxr-x  13 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Dec 14 23:27 .
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root     root      4096 Jan  5 12:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Nov 18 15:03 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb 17987 Dec 14 14:25 COPYING
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb 26545 Dec 14 14:25 COPYING.LESSER
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb 86259 Dec 14 14:25 COPYING.thirdparty                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb  2122 Dec 14 14:25 CREDITS                                                                                                                      
drwxrwxr-x   4 mysql    Gmariadb  4096 Mar  8 20:25 data                                                                                                                         
drwxrwxr-x   2 Umariadb Gmariadb    30 Dec 14 23:26 DESTINATION                                                                                                                  
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb  8245 Dec 14 14:25 EXCEPTIONS-CLIENT                                                                                                            
drwxrwxr-x   3 Umariadb Gmariadb    18 Dec 14 23:26 include                                                                                                                      
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb  8694 Dec 14 14:25 INSTALL-BINARY                                                                                                               
drwxrwxr-x   4 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Nov 18 15:03 lib                                                                                                                          
drwxrwxr-x   4 Umariadb Gmariadb    28 Dec 14 23:27 man                                                                                                                          
drwxrwxr-x  11 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Dec 14 23:26 mysql-test                                                                                                                   
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb  2105 Dec 14 14:25 README                                                                                                                       
-rw-r--r--   1 Umariadb Gmariadb 19510 Dec 14 14:25 README-wsrep                                                                                                                 
drwxrwxr-x   2 Umariadb Gmariadb    29 Dec 14 23:27 scripts                                                                                                                      
drwxrwxr-x  29 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Dec 14 23:26 share
drwxrwxr-x   4 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Dec 14 23:27 sql-bench
drwxrwxr-x   3 Umariadb Gmariadb  4096 Jan  4 22:32 support-files
```

I noted on the data folder, the ownership is belong to (mysql:mysql) after of installation, but I thought it was that service script problem (mariadb.service)...

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ ls -al /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/
total 110624
drwxrwxr-x  4 mysql    Gmariadb     4096 Mar  8 20:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 Umariadb Gmariadb     4096 Dec 14 23:27 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql       16384 Mar  8 19:59 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql          52 Mar  8 19:59 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql    12582912 Mar  8 19:59 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql    50331648 Mar  8 19:59 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql    50331648 Jan  4 22:01 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql           0 Jan  4 22:05 multi-master.info
drwx------  2 mysql    root         4096 Jan  4 22:01 mysql
drwx------  2 mysql    mysql          19 Jan  4 22:01 performance_schema
-rw-rw----  1 mysql    mysql           0 Mar  8 20:04 server.err
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

@Kalavan confirmed my suspicion of ownership, then I needed to change the ownership after installation process ...

```
sudo chown -R Umariadb:Gmariadb /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/
```

I reboot my CentOS 7, and the service was WORKING!!!

I Checked the log file */usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err*..

```
170308 20:36:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
2017-03-08 20:36:23 140485189175168 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.20-MariaDB) starting as process 2360 ...
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-08 20:36:24 140485189175168 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1622948
2017-03-08 20:36:25 140485189175168 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-08 20:36:25 140484651484928 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-08 20:36:25 140485189175168 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-03-08 20:36:25 140485189175168 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.20-MariaDB'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

*Checking PID*

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ ps -aux | grep mariadb
mysql     1652  0.0  0.1 113264  1656 ?        Ss   11:42   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
mysql     2458  0.2  5.6 591028 87172 ?        Sl   11:42   0:00 /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err --pid-file=Vxbox-Lnx.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
joselui+  4489  0.0  0.0 112652   964 pts/0    R+   11:44   0:00 grep --color=auto mariadb
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

Effectively mariadb is running!!!

*I checked the Status*

```
$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
● mariadb.service - start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-03-10 11:42:07 COT; 17min ago
Main PID: 1652 (mysqld_safe)
  CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
      ├─1652 /bin/sh /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data...
      └─2458 /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Ser...

Mar 10 11:42:07 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: Started start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server.
Mar 10 11:42:07 Vxbox-Lnx systemd[1]: Starting start and stop MySQL(MariaDB) Server...
Mar 10 11:42:09 Vxbox-Lnx mysqld_safe[1652]: 170310 11:42:09 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err'.
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

But *I can't connect!!*

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$
```

I check the existence of the *mysql.sock* file (but, there is not)...

```
# ls -al /tmp/
total 24
drwxrwxrwt. 22 root       root       4096 Mar 10 12:28 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root       root       4096 Feb 18 21:21 ..
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   52 Mar 10 11:42 akonadi-joseluisbz.Fim4n9
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   50 Mar 10 09:20 .com.google.Chrome.I956Ja
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   50 Mar 10 07:38 .com.google.Chrome.ibPaUS
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   50 Mar  9 07:31 .com.google.Chrome.oIW6st
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   50 Mar  8 19:22 .com.google.Chrome.pGYMUt
drwx------.  2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   19 Mar 10 11:42 .esd-1000
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root       root          6 Oct 10 20:09 .font-unix
prw-------   1 root       root          0 Mar 10 11:42 hogsuspend
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root       root       4096 Mar 10 11:42 .ICE-unix
drwx------.  2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   50 Mar 10 12:25 kde-joseluisbz
drwx------   2 root       root         23 Mar 10 11:44 kde-root
drwx------   2 root       root       4096 Mar 10 11:44 ksocket-root
drwx------   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   23 Mar 10 11:42 ssh-aOJwbK0vltXX
drwx------   3 root       root         16 Mar 10 11:42 systemd-private-65b25dd58edd4711ad864dc007925904-colord.service-EVVMql
drwx------   3 root       root         16 Mar 10 11:42 systemd-private-65b25dd58edd4711ad864dc007925904-cups.service-jOD1sm
drwx------   3 root       root         16 Mar 10 11:42 systemd-private-65b25dd58edd4711ad864dc007925904-mariadb.service-eioofZ
drwx------   3 root       root         16 Mar  9 15:11 systemd-private-65b25dd58edd4711ad864dc007925904-rtkit-daemon.service-E5cH4Y
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root       root          6 Oct 10 20:09 .Test-unix
drwx------.  2 joseluisbz joseluisbz    6 Oct 10 20:42 tracker-extract-files.1000
-r--r--r--   1 root       root         11 Mar 10 11:42 .X0-lock
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root       root         24 Mar 10 11:42 .X11-unix
-rw-------   1 root       root         54 Mar 10 08:35 xauth.XXXXTFUQeQ
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root       root          6 Oct 10 20:09 .XIM-unix
[root@Vxbox-Lnx joseluisbz]#
```

Then I changed the config file */etc/my.cnf* changing the socket location, and sure the ownership (to respective user:group) folder of its location...

```
[client]
...
socket      = /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
...

[mysqld]
...
socket      = /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
...
```

And created the folder tmp for socket and ensuring the ownership again!

```
sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/tmp
sudo chown -R Umariadb:Gmariadb /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/
```

LATER of this changes and rebooting CentOS 7

Verifing log file */usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data/server.err*..

```
170311 17:31:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/data
2017-03-11 17:31:50 139805859948416 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.20-MariaDB) starting as process 2187 ...
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1623144
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805379786496 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-11 17:31:51 139805859948416 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-03-11 17:31:52 139805859948416 [Note] /usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.20-MariaDB'  socket: '/usr/local/ServerWeb/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

Starting the client...

```
[joseluisbz@Vxbox-Lnx ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 10.1.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Works perfectly...

**Resume of solution**

- The order of changed Ownership to Umariadb:Gmariadb *Only* after of Installation.
- Changing location of Socket where user:group can to write...

**NOTE**: The original file */etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service* has not problem!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/* /opt/
```